# Spatial Correlation of raster layer to point layer

Tags: qgis, raster, autocorrelation

I'm a new GIS user and hoping you all can point me in the right direction.

I have a raster overlaid with point values in QGIS as seen below. The values of the raster field range from low (blue) to high (red). I am trying to quantify the correlation of high raster values to proximity to each point but am not sure what the best method is or if this type of functionality is included in QGIS.

[image]

Comment: Well, if this is typical of your data you have a bigger issue. It looks like you have numerous points falling into the same pixels. This is indicative of a lack of independence and is a serious pseudoreplication problem.

Comment: The points are buildings so they are certainly not independent. I'm trying to determine whether these clusters affect surrounding raster values.

Comment: You will never be able to support the inference, even anecdotally, that clusters affect surrounding raster values because your data is very pseudoreplicated. This is very much influenced by a scale mismatch in your data. Correlations are a bit of a non sequitur here because you are sampling the same thing repeatedly. Now, if you have repeated measures, in other areas, that look like this, you can treat each one as an experimental unit and aggregate them into single observations. You could then just use something like a t-test to evaluate independence, or lack thereof.

Comment: This exactly what I was looking for. I wasn't exactly sure what the best tool was to use.

Comment: I am sure that you can assign the raster values to the points and perform the data aggregation in QGIS but, you still need the statistical test. I can give you very simple guidance for this entire workflow in R (just add an R tag) but, not QGIS.

Comment: To get the raster value for a point layer, use this expression with field calculator: `raster_value( 'raster', 1, $geometry)` - replace `raster` with the name of your raster layer and `1` with the band you want to get the value from